# While loop w/ 2 loops inside looping to wrong spot Python3

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a realy basic calculater program written in python 3. The first while is so the user can be prompted to do another problem after the answer is given. The subsequent loops are for validating the user inputs.

For some reason the loops inside work fine and the main one will work if I choose to close the program, however, if I choose to do another problem it loops to asking for a number instead of the beginning asking what problem.

```
while True:
# User inputs type of problem & input is validated
    while True:
        problem = input()

        if problem not in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):
            print('You did not make a valid selection, please try again.')
        else:
            break

# User inputs numbers for problems & input is validated
    while True:
        num1 = input('Please input the first number in the problem')
        num2 = input('Please input the second number in the problem')
        isnum1 = is_number(num1)
        isnum2 = is_number(num2)

        if isnum1 is False or isnum2 is False:
            print('You did not enter a number')
        else:
            num1 = float(num1)
            num2 = float(num2)
            break

# Perform appropriate math
    ans = 0
    if problem == '1':
        ans = num1 + num2
        print(num1, '+', num2, '=', ans)
    elif problem == '2':
        ans = num1 - num2
        print(num1, '-', num2, '=', ans)
    elif problem == '3':
        ans = num1 * num2
        print(num1, '*', num2, '=', ans)
    elif problem == '4':
        ans = num1 / num2
        print(num1, '/', num2, '=', ans)

# Ask if user would like to perform another problem or exit
    nxt = input('Would you like to do another problem?\n 1 - Yes\n 2 - No')

    if nxt not in ('1', '2'):
        print('You did not make a valid selection.')
    elif nxt == '2':
        break

exit(0)
```

Comment: Can you please first fix your indentation? Or is this how it is in your program (If so, how is it running?) .

Comment: The first while won't move all the way over but it is lined up with the exit(0) in my program

Comment: It still looks incorrectly indented. You shouldn't use <pre><code> yourself; properly copy-paste your original code, then use the code-block formatting option (the {} icon) to format the code.

Comment: @GrantJordan is this Python 2.x ? If so, are you mixing tabs and spaces, to me it looks like mixing of tabs and spaces.

Comment: You should definitely look into using `if`/`elif`

Comment: Thank you for the if/elif tip, that cleaned up that section nice. Unfortunately I still have the loop problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `problem` does not leave scope, so is still defined and you break out of the first loop.

This is your first loop:

```
while True:
    problem = input()

    if problem not in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):
        print('You did not make a valid selection, please try again.')
    else:
        break
```

`problem` is not defined prior to this. But it *is* defined after this. So when the outer `while` loop loops, problem will remain defined. Thus, your second `if` clause (the `else`) will execute, breaking.

To prove this, do this:

```
while True:
    problem = input()

    if problem not in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):
        print('You did not make a valid selection, please try again.')
    else:
        print('You have made a valid selection: {}".format(problem))  # This will display, showing that the loop is executed.
        break
```

To fix it, do this:

```
problem = None
while True:
    problem = input()

    if problem not in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):
        print('You did not make a valid selection, please try again.')
    else:
        print('You have made a valid selection: {}".format(problem))
        break
```

Comment: You're welcome, of course! It may be that you're still inside the time limit. Be sure to accept answers that help you, too!

Answer (score 1):

As Nathaniel stated, I left `problem` definied. However if I just set `problem = None` prior to the loop then there are no instructions to prompt the user to choose a problem.

So instead I changed this code:

```
    if nxt not in ('1', '2'):
        print('You did not make a valid selection.')
    elif nxt == '2':
        break
```

To this:

```
if nxt not in ('1', '2'):
    print('You did not make a valid selection.')
elif nxt =='1':
    print('Please select the type of problem you would like to complete.\n 1 - Addition\n 2 - Subtraction\n 3 - Multiplication\n 4 - Division\n')
    problem = 0
elif nxt == '2':
    break
```

Everything works great now. Thanks for the point in the right direction Nathaniel.